# How to fully lock the GNOME-panel?

Tags: gnome

I know I can lock elements on GNOME-panel that prevent users to move the element on the GNOME-panel, but how can I fully lock the GNOME-panel? I mean I need a locking mechanism, that will prevent accidentally removing of elements, like ex.: the user deletes the clock from the GNOME-panel.

Are there any solutions to lock it? version 2.30.2-0ubuntu0.2

Comment: @harish.venkat This should be an answer!

Comment: If nothing else works, make the configuration read-only. Then, a user could accidentally muck up a single session, but logging out would fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Press Alt-F2 and run gconf-editor. Go to apps--> panel-->global and there the key "locked down" should do the trick ,i think so

Comment: That's brilliant!